# Render a component from child function

Tags: reactjs

I'm a little bit new to React so I'm not even sure what am I looking for but this is the problem I have:

I've created a top navbar that need to be there for all the pages, but each page need to "fill" the navbar with a different content, and I want only the different content to render instead of re-rendering the navbar over and over again.

[image: top navbar]

this is the navbar code inside app.jsx:

```
<Router>
    <div className="wrapper">

      {/* Sidebar */}
      <RbzNavbar />

      <div id="content">
        {/* Top navbar */}
        <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
          <div className="container-fluid">

            <div className="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" className="btn btn-default navbar-btn">
                <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i>
              </button>
            </div>

            {/* some function to render the top navbar content for eact page */}

          </div>
        </nav>

        {/* Pages routes and components */}
        <Route exact path='/' component={RbzDashboard} />
        <Route exact path='/application-tree' component={RbzApplicationTree} />
        <Route exact path='/planet' component={RbzStaticRules} />
      </div>
    </div>
  </Router>
```

I want to create some function like {this.renderNavbar} that will be implemented for each page in the router.

Answer (score 0):

Each component only gets re-rendered if it's state changes. So you don't need to worry about repeated rendering, and in any case React has the shadow DOM, so if a component is re-rendered, it does a diff before actually updating the DOM, so it's pretty efficient.

Answer (score 0):

One of the way of achieving what you want is like this.

Like you said you can create a `renderNav` function but only for the component contains the routes and you can pass that function as a prop to your child components and run it.

**Example** *(Not tested)*

```
setNavData = (navData) => {
  // this will change the state and navigation will be re-rendered
  this.setState({navData});
}

renderNav = () => {
  // render nav according to state
  return this.state.navData.map((navItem) => <a href="#">{navItem.name}</a>);
}

//Then you can pass setNavBar as a prop to Child

render() {
  return(
    <Router>
    <div className="wrapper">

      {/* Sidebar */}
      <RbzNavbar />

      <div id="content">
        {/* Top navbar */}
        <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
          <div className="container-fluid">

            <div className="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" id="sidebarCollapse" className="btn btn-default navbar-btn">
                <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i>
              </button>
            </div>

            {this.renderNav}

          </div>
        </nav>

        {/* Pages routes and components */}
        <Route exact path='/' render={() => <RbzDashboard changeNavStructure={this.setNavData} />} />
        <Route exact path='/application-tree' render={() => <RbzApplicationTree changeNavStructure={this.setNavData} />} />
        <Route exact path='/planet' render={() => <RbzStaticRules changeNavStructure={this.setNavData} />} />
      </div>
    </div>
  </Router>
  )
} 

// lastly in your child component

componentWillMount() {
  this.props.changeNavStructure([{name: 'Home'}, {name: 'Contact'}, {name: 'PRofile'}]);
}
```